# How can I use docker-compose to deploy to production using an env_file on the server?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Take the following simplified example:

```yaml
services:
  app:
    image: alpine
    env_file: config.env
    entrypoint:
      - /bin/sh
      - -c
      - 'echo "Var is: $$MY_VAR"'
```

I have `config.env` locally with my local dev settings, and a `config.env` on the server with production settings.

When I use `docker-compose -H user@example.com up --build -d`, it uses my local config.env instead of the one on the server. I'd rather not store environment-specific configuration in my repository, however the methods recommended in the docker documentation all involve making separate `.yml` files or `.env` files on the same machine on which you're using `docker-compose`.

So, my question is, how can I store configuration on my server, and use `docker-compose` on my dev machine to deploy? Or am I better off just uploading the repo to the server and running `docker-compose` there so I can use the remote env file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually went with creating my own deploy script that copies the docker-compose files to the server and using an environment file on the server:

```sh
scp docker-compose.yml $USER@$HOST:/tmp/
deploy_cmd="export \$(grep -v '#.*' \"$REMOTE_ENV_FILE\" | xargs)";
deploy_cmd="$deploy_cmd && docker stack deploy -c /tmp/docker-compose.yml my-project";
echo "Deploying to $USER@$HOST"
ssh -qA "$USER@$HOST" "$deploy_cmd" || return 1;
```